# SPARQL Querying filter based on property of an item

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am brand new to SPARQL (started today to help a friend)

Basically, I am unsure on the syntax/query set up required, if I want to filter/restrict based on some property of an item I have already queried for.

For example in the below query, I output a film's title, genre, publication date and director, and I have restricted the search to those films with a 'country of origin' in Australia. I was wondering if instead, I could filter for Australian films based upon, say, the citizenship of the films director being necessarily Australian.

So how might I specify essentially that I want the director to satisfy `wdt:P27` `wd:Q408`? (country of citizenship is Australia)

```
SELECT ?filmLabel ?genreLabel ?publicationLabel ?directorLabel
WHERE {
  ?film 
  wdt:P31 wd:Q11424; #  PROPERTY: instance of           OBJECT: film
  wdt:P495 wd:Q408;  #  PROPERTY: country of origin     OBJECT: Australia
  wdt:P136 ?genre;   #  PROPERTY: genre                 OBJECT: film's genre (don't restrict)
  wdt:P577 ?publication; # PROPERTY: publication date   OBJECT: film's publication date (don't restrict)
  wdt:P57 ?director;     # PROPERTY: director           OBJECT: film's director (don't restrict)
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
  # Allows you to display label info of objects, rather than Q number  
}
```

Thanks very much for reading, apologies its such a basic question.

I tried to use the FILTER function e.g.
`FILTER(?director wdt:P27 wd:Q408)`,
and also tried just
`?director wdt:P27 wd:Q408`
after all the film stuff.

Comment: Isn't adding another triple pattern `?director wdt:P27 wd:Q408` what you want?

Comment: you should also consider merging the `genres` and think about that a film can have multiple release dates, so what data you'd prefer - if not, this leads to multiple rows aka bindings for the same film.

Comment: UninformedUser, I am not sure how to get that to work tbh